how does firebase charge for the count() aggregation query
According to firebase documentation, when you use the count aggregation query, you are charged according to the number of index reads that are done.  However this is contradicted by the statement from Frank van Puffelen here
new count() aggregation function performance
who said you are charged according to the value of the count returned in response to the query.
If you do a count query that involves two "where" clauses e.g.
.where("country", isEqualTo: "United States")
.where("age", isGreaterThan: "100")

where the first where clause finds 100,000 matches and the second where clause reduces the match count to 900, the count returned is 900.  According to Frank you get charged for one read (900 divided by 1000, plus one).  However, since 100,000 indexes were read, I'm wondering if you get charged for 100,000 divided by 1000 reads  i.e. you get charged for 100 reads.
Furthermore, the firebase documentation here
https://cloud.google.com/firestore/pricing#index-reads
says this

Queries that have up to one range field are not charged for index
entries read.

so for the example I gave above, this means you are not charged for any index reads at all.  So which is correct for the example I gave

Frank is correct - you are charged for one read
You are charged for 100 reads
You are not charged anything at all


Answer below. If this isn't how you understood the documentation, please provide a link to the documentation - so we can clarify it. If this is not the behavior you see in practice, please show a more complete code sample.

Thanks for answering.  Despite having read through this page a few times (https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries)
I was completely unaware of what a composite index was and that you have to manually create them.  My use case is that I have a potentially large collection of "user documents" containing surname, first name, full name and username fields and I was hoping to allow someone to search for a user by typing in part or all of their surname and part or all of their first name, however I see now this isn't going to work.

Also, this page (https://cloud.google.com/firestore/pricing#index-reads) gives this example
db.collection("employees").whereEqualTo("age", 35)
.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("start_date", new Date(2020, 1, 1))
and says that for this example, you don't get charged for index entries read - and further below it says this applies to aggregation queries also.

I think/suggest that this page should explain what composite queries are
https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/multiple-range-fields
and also explain that the number of index reads for a count query is equal to the returned count value for both single field queries and composite queries.

The documentation on this page
https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries
implies that I don't need a composite index to do a combination of "== AND array-contains" which I think will let me do my first-name surname query by using array-contains for the surname and a bunch explicit prefix fields for the first name e.g. if the user has typed 5 characters for part of the first name
.where("FN-prefix5", isEqualTo: "abcde")
.where("surname-prefixes", arrayContains: surname-prefix)

Great feedback! Please click the Send feedback link at the top of those pages to ensure it reaches the right person.

Firestore uses a dedicated index for the query you specify. So your two conditions identify a single slice of data in the composite index that is used.
If the count query with your condition returns a count of 900, it scanned 900 index items for that count and you get charged 1 document read for that.

So for a single field AND query like this
.where("surname", isGreaterThan: "will")
.where("surname", isLessThan: "wilk")
if the count value returned is 900, does that still mean it scanned 900 index items and you get charged one document read?
